# foreign key serialization in python

Tags: django, api, serialization

I have appropriate models. App work on MacOS, but on linux I have mistake

> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'

When I add task from admin I get mistake like

> (1366, "Incorrect string value: '\xD0\xBE\xD1\x80\xD0\xBF...'
>   for column 'title' at row 1")

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from users.models import User
from task.models import Task


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'user_type', 'balance')


class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    assignee = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    created_by = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'description', 'money', 'assignee', 'created_by')

    def get_assignee(self, obj):
        return {
            'id': obj.assignee.id,
            'username': obj.assignee.username,
            'first_name': obj.assignee.first_name,
            'last_name': obj.assignee.last_name,
            'user_type': obj.assignee.user_type,
            'balance': obj.assignee.balance
        }

    def get_created_by(self, obj):
        return {
            'id': obj.created_by.id,
            'username': obj.created_by.username,
            'first_name': obj.created_by.first_name,
            'last_name': obj.created_by.last_name,
            'user_type': obj.created_by.user_type,
            'balance': obj.created_by.balance,
        }
```

Comment: You have an encoding problem, but you haven't shared enough information to figure out exactly what the issue is. It looks like the character set for your database table is wrong. Share the text you're trying to insert into the `title` field, and the output of `DESCRIBE task_task` in MySQL.

Comment: I try to input Russian text, it is something like "название"

Comment: Your database character set/collation is likely set to something like `latin1`/`latin1_swedish_ci` and can't decode the bytes you're trying to insert. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/unicode/#creating-the-database. You want a character set of `utf8` and a collation of `utf8_unicode_ci` (or similar).

Comment: I change character set, but still have same mistake mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE'character%';
| character_set_client     | utf8                       |
| character_set_connection | utf8                       |
| character_set_database   | latin1                     |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8                       |
| character_set_server     | latin1                     |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall everything in MySQL, now it works.